# How to install Flink on Mesos cluster without DC/OS?

Tags: apache-flink, mesos, marathon

I am newbie in Apache Flink and our team is trying to set up an Apache Flink Cluster on Apaches Mesos. We have already installed Apache Mesos & Marathon with 3 Master nodes and 3 Slaves and now we are trying to install Apache Flink without DC/OS as mentioned here https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/setup/mesos.html#mesos-without-dcos.

I have couple of questions over here :

1. Do we need to download Flink on all the nodes(master and slaves) and configure mesos.master in all nodes?
2. Or Shall we download flink on only one master node and configure mesos.master over there?
3. If flink needs to be downloaded on all the nodes then what should be the location of flink directory or if there is any script where I can specify that?
4. Is running "mesos-appmaster.sh" on master node also responsible for running flink libraries and classes on slaves?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. > Do we need to download Flink on all the nodes(master and slaves) and configure mesos.master in all nodes?

   No you don't. Actualy it depends on the way you want to run Flink. In your setup the most convenient way to run Flink would be to run it with Marathon and download binaries during deployment. [See this](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/setup/mesos.html#pre-installing-flink-vs-dockermesos-containers)
2. > Or Shall we download flink on only one master node and configure mesos.master over there?

   It's up to you. You can run Flink on dedicated server or let Marathon do it for you. If you already have Marathon then it's easier to run Flink with Marathon. On the other hand for debugging purposes and proof of concept I'll recommend standalone version where you can quickly change configuration on local machine and see how it works. Creating docker images or binaries and publishing them in repository and finally deploying Flink on Marathon could have more overhead that will slow you down on development but will keep you safe on production. Flink does not come with support for High Availability (HA) so Marathon is required to provide basic HA support (launch new instance of Flink when agent crash).
3. > If flink needs to be downloaded on all the nodes then what should be the location of flink directory or if there is any script where I can specify that?

   Flink does not have to be downloaded on all nodes. It can be downloaded when needed at deployment.
4. > Is running "mesos-appmaster.sh" on master node also responsible for running flink libraries and classes on slaves?

   Flink is a scheduler which means that it should start tasks and executors on Mesos when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Even when not using DC/OS, feel free to look at the [Apache Flink DC/OS package](https://github.com/mesosphere/universe/tree/version-3.x/repo/packages/F/flink/6). At its core, it is a marathon app definition you can deploy on pure Marathon/Mesos. The Flink package (as of today) does not require any DC/OS specific features.

The [DC/OS example](https://github.com/dcos/examples/tree/master/flink/1.9) might also provide useful information.